# Build and guard against missing library using Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I have a library (`lib.a`) and a header file (`lib1.h`). The problem is the library is too big and only a relatively small subset of users need it.

- Would it be possible to build my Xcode project without the library? Currently I get:

> ld: library not found for -llib
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

- Would it be possible to guard against usage of the library not existing inside the Xcode project? I [found the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10068079/186909), but I'm not sure if it's sufficient (assuming I can get the project to build without the lib):

  `if ([MyLibABC class]) { ... } else { NSLog(@"Add Lib.a"); }`

**Side note:**

In Java I would [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16292985/186909) to call methods implemented in the library (`lib.jar`) and if the library is not present I would catch the [ClassNotFoundException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassNotFoundException.html) and show an error message or something (*lib.jar missing, please consult the documentation*).

I'm targeting >= iOS5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike desktop operating systems which support dynamic libraries, [iOS supports only static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4733885/335858). The only way around this would be building two targets - one that uses the library, and the other one that does not.

You can build both targets from the same set of sources by using [*conditional compilation*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4441397/335858). In the version that conditionally compiles out the references to the "big library" there would be no references to it, so the linker would not complain about missing references.